# Fiddler/C#: search content of request/response for special phrases

Tags: c#, fiddler

this is my first visit to stackoverflow and right now I feel very comfortable with this site.

It already helped me to get the [FiddlerCore](http://www.fiddlertool.com/Fiddler/Core/) embedded into MS Visual C# 2008 Express Edition.
Just needed to create a reference(Verweis) to the fiddlercore dll from Project Explorer(Projektmappenexplorer) in MS Visual C# EE. Hope this are the names for it in the english version. After this you can use Fiddler.FiddlerApplication stuff etc.

### What is my task?

I want to create a small program which is able to use the FiddlerCore to check the bodies of requests/responds for special JavaScript Code.
This enables the developers to check wether their code is valid in another versions of there Browser (especially from IE 6.x to IE 8.x) or not. To be able to do so, I need to know:

### How can I check the content of a requested or responded file for a String?

***This must have something to do with the Text View Inspector (Fiddler), but I cannot find a possibility to access it with .net code or within Fiddler which would also help a lot already.***

I should be able to finish the remaining stuff with some search by google or stackoverflow.
As this is my first time with .net languages this will be very interesting and demanding.

Comment: +1: Excellent question and well written. Wish I could provide more help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [this example](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore-demo). In the `BeforeResponse` callback a `Fiddler.Session` is passed as argument. This object has a method called `GetResponseBodyAsString`. As its name suggest you may try using it to get the response text. There's also a `GetRequestBodyAsString` method for the request.

Comment: sounds like exactly what I was searching for - so I will check this and come back - thanks a lot so far!

Comment: Yup, that's the best way to get started.